# How to unadvise using AopJS

Tags: javascript, aop

I'm looking to use [AopJS](https://github.com/victorcastroamigo/aopjs), but I can't find any function to unadvise; is there any trick to unadvise while using this library.

Comment: Ah, apparently "advise" means something in AOP, and so "unadvise" is its opposite. Be careful with that spelling: "to advise" is a verb, "some advice" is a noun, and they are not interchangeable.

Comment: Regarding the `AOP` tag, wrapping and reassigning already declared functionality (be it functions or methods) misses any aspect of _AOP_. Any language which wants to qualify for the latter has to provide abstraction levels for at least `Joinpoint`, `Advice` and `Aspect`. The use case described by the OP should be referred to as method modification, and JavaScript of cause is well suited for this scenario and could easily provide a complete `target`/`context` aware toolset of method modifiers like `around`, `before`, `after`, `afterThrowing` and `afterFinally` via `Function.prototype`.